# Multi-stage build fail to find file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

It's my first I use multi-stage and I have this error when I run the `docker-compose up`:

> worker_1  | Error: Unable to access jarfile worker-jar-with-dependencies.jar

So it looks like it doesn't found the file.

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine AS builder
ADD pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:resolve
#RUN /bin/sh -c cd src/
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY --from=builder target/worker-jar-with-dependencies.jar .
#RUN java -jar worker-jar-with-dependencies.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "worker-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```

and how it looks my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'
services:
    poll:
        build: poll/.
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        networks: 
            - poll-tier
    redis:
        image: "redis"
        expose: 
            - "6379"
        networks:
            - back-tier
            - poll-tier
    worker:
        build: worker/.
        networks: 
            - back-tier
    db:
        image: "postgres"
        volumes:
            - "db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
        networks:
            - back-tier
            - result-tier
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: popeye
    
    result:
        build: result/.
        ports:
            - "5001:80"
        networks: 
            - result-tier
    
volumes:
    db-data:
networks:
    poll-tier: {}
    result-tier: {}
    back-tier: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are adding your source code in the Dockerfile.  You only have an ADD command for your pom, but there isn't one for your source.  I would say adding something like "COPY src /src" before your "RUN mvn package".

Not sure if you are using springboot, but here is an example of a multi stage build for a springboot app:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 AS builder
WORKDIR /workdir/server
COPY pom.xml /workdir/server/pom.xml
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY src /workdir/server/src
RUN mvn install
RUN mkdir  -p target/depency
WORKDIR /workdir/server/target/dependency
RUN jar -xf ../*.jar

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workdir/server/target/dependency
COPY --from=builder ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=builder ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=builder ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.company.project.Application"]
```

You can find this and other good docker-compose examples in this docker repo: https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose

Comment: I would also add that it is a good idea to explicitly specify `WORKDIR` and use absolute paths when copying between stages - both are demonstrated in the sample `Dockerfile`.